# Spherical cap area is $\pi r^2$. But why?

Tags: geometry, area, spherical-geometry

(If you're surprised by the title — $r$ is not what you (perhaps) think it is : )

Let $x$ be a point on a sphere $S$ and let $U$ be some sphere with center $x$ that intersects $S$.

> **Claim¹.** The spherical cap cut out from $S$ and the circle cut out from $T_xS$ (tangent plane to $S$ at $x$) have the same area.

[image: illustration (by etudes.ru)]

In other words, the area of a spherical cap is $\pi r^2$ where $r$ is the distance from its center $x$ to its boundary. (So we have a very simple formula for circle area in spherical geometry. But it's somewhat strange: $r$ is neither spherical nor Euclidean radius of the circle!)

> **Question.** How to prove this geometrically?

It can be proved by direct computation² but surely there should be… some explanation why this map from a sphere to a plane is area-preserving, perhaps?

One interesting special case is $r=2R$ (where $R$ is the radius of $S$). The 'cap' in this case is the whole sphere — and $\pi r^2=4\pi R^2$. So a (good) answer to my question would give (yet another) explanation of sphere's surface area formula.

---

¹ I learned this from A. Akopyan.

² For example: the height of the cap is $r^2/2R$ (because $h/r=(r/2)/R$), so by Archimedes' hatbox lemma the area is $2\pi R\cdot r^2/2R=\pi r^2$.

Comment: What is "$T_xS$"? From context, I guess it means "the plane tangent to $S$ at $x$", but I'd rather not guess. ... Also, rather than giving a potentially "shocking" title, why not given an *informative* one?

Comment: It's not totally clear from the phrasing. Based on trying to sketch it out I am guessing:
$R$ is the radius of the sphere $S$,
$r$ is the radius of the sphere $U$, and
"the circle" is cut out of the tangent plane at $x$, at the intersection of that plane with $U$

Comment: @Blue Thank you, I've explained the notation

Comment: As for the title… The question is about area of a spherical cup — and specifically about simple and unexpected formula for this area — so maybe you don't find the title amusing, but imho it's quite informative.

Comment: related (but slightly different construction) explained by Mathologer: https://youtu.be/5q_sfXY-va8

Answer (score 8):

I don’t know a simple geometric explanation for the total area, but infinitesimally, if the arc length is $a$ and the chord length is $r$, in the limit of small increments $da$ and $dr$, by similar triangles we have:

$$\frac{da}{dr}=\frac{r}{\rho}$$

where $\rho$ is the orthogonal distance of the endpoint of the arc/chord from a diameter that passes through the starting point.  In spherical coordinates, $\rho = R \sin \theta$.

If the area of the spherical cap is $A$, we have:

$$\frac{dA}{da} = 2\pi \rho$$
$$\frac{dA}{dr} = \frac{dA}{da} \frac{da}{dr} = 2\pi r $$

[image: Diagram showing infinitesimal triangle]

Answer (score 3):

Not a fully geometric proof of why the map preserves areas, but hope it helps.

[image]